# ASP.net - How to put a recordset in cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have around 100 rows in database ( which can increase in future ) for different labels used in page. These rows are required on all pages. I want to do it in a way that I get these rows once from db and put some where in cache or something similar to that. So that i don't have to query database on every page refresh. And how can this cache be used by all site visitors?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cache Variables something like this :

```
Cache["COMMON_DATA"] = lstData (This can be any collection like LIST<Country>)
```

You can also use SqlCacheDependency in asp.net that will auto reset your cache if more rows are added in the the database

else you can update the Cache again manually after inserting data in the table

Answer (score 0):

[Caching in ASP.net](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/655/caching-in-aspnet/) and [Application State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Application_state) would be a couple of ideas for you.